# Keyboard shortcut is unstable Alt, Super etc

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, xdotool

I want to set keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 14.04
but it does not work properly.

I use CompizConfig Settings Manager > Commands
Rather than not work at all, sometimes it works.

When I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> to Key Binding, work is unstable.
So is <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is stable work.

The settings

Commands `~/Documents/Scripts/paste.sh`
Key Bindings `<Alt>v`

paste.sh

> xdotool keydown ctrl 
> sleep .1 
> xdotool key v key ctrl

Thank you.

Comment: that's because super F1 is already in use, in compiz, you need to use keybindings that aren't already in use, then it will work just fine

Comment: Thank you! I want to use Alt most.  Alt is already in use too?

Comment: I try using shift+alt+key, ctrl+alt+key, or shift+ctrl+alt+key instead. But don't work properly. If use alt or shift, then failed.

Comment: I want to paste the content of the clipboard by Alt + v.

Comment: I found the problem, also, you don't need a script to run, just enter the command in ccsm

Answer (score 0):

Open ccsm:

```
ccsm &
```

Go to keyboard **shortcuts** and set the following command:

```
xdotool key ctrl+v
```

You will have to mess around with keybindings to find one that works. I tried <kbd>F1</kbd> and it works fine. You cannot use <kbd>ALT</kbd> as far as I can tell because <kbd>ALT</kbd> is binded to the menu.